# Extend Windows Server 2008 evaluation period after it has expired

Tags: windows-server-2008

I downloaded and installed [Windows Server 2008 Trial](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=13C7300E-935C-415A-A79C-538E933D5424&displaylang=en). It expires after 60 days, but is extendable to 240 days all in all by logging into the server and running a command.

[Here is how I should extend my trial according to MS Support](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/948472).

My problem is, that I just came back from a vacation to find the server will no longer allow me to log in without activating (ie the 60 days passed while I was away) - so I cannot perform the steps specified in the link.

Is there something I can do, or do I have to reinstall it from scratch?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1.After logging in (you must be logged in as an administrator to do this, so do so if you’re not already), you’ll be asked to enter a key or use Windows in reduced functionality mode.  Click the option for using reduced functionality mode.

2.In the web browser you’re presented with, type “C:\Windows\System32″ in the address bar and hit enter.

3.Find cmd.exe in the System32 folder, right click on it, and choose “Run as Administrator”.

4.When UAC prompts you to elevate permissions, click allow.

5.Type “slmgr -rearm” at the command prompt and hit enter.

6.Reboot.

Answer (score 1):

You can use that tool to talk to your 2008 installation remotely.

More info can be found here: http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles_tutorials/Windows-Server-License-Manager-Script-slmgrvbs.html

Comment: I can't make that work, I keep getting the message that the scripting host cannot connect to the address (I supply an ip-address). I can still connect to the webserver from a browser, the sql server etc...